# Lame running on java: err console log

Tags: java, ubuntu, mp3, wav, lame

I'm running lame to convert a WAV sound in MP3, executing as console application:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"lame", "in.wav", "out.mp3", "-b", "128"});
Process p = pb.start();
try {
    p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    logger.error("Error calling lame", ie);
}
```

When I'm reading the output, the "normal" output is empty, but the `err` has values. It's an execution error, or the lame do all output as `err`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See yourself. Run that command in terminal and redirect stdout and stderr to different files. Then you'll know where it goes:

```
lame in.wav out.mp3 -b 128 1>stdout 2>stderr
```